# Return the maximum value to the left of the cells containing a given string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For an Excel spreadsheet, I am trying to find the maximum number that corresponds to a cell with a certain string. For instance, if the data is:

```
   | A | B    |
1  | 3 | Red  |
2  | 5 | Blue |
3  | 1 | Blue |
4  | 4 | Red  |
5  | 4 | Blue |
```

And the string is "Red", then it will return 4. If the string was "Blue", then it would return 5.

For various reasons, it is very inconvenient to format the data as a table, so (as far as I know) a simple VLOOKUP won't do the trick. Also, I can't use Array formulas because I want the formula to be in a merged cell. If it is at all possible, I would also like to avoid using macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array formula (one that is entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead <kbd>Enter</kbd> only):

```
=MAX(IF(B1:B5="Red",A1:A5))
```

And this one is for blue:

```
=MAX(IF(B1:B5="Blue",A1:A5))
```

Be sure to enter those with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for them to work.

---

Otherwise, you can use a pivot table:

[image]